# Change Terminal Colors without changing vim colors?

Tags: bash, vim, colors

Is there is a way of changing terminal colors without changing the colors in terminal VIM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CSApprox` package in order to use Vim's color themes on a terminal that supports the xterm 256 color extension. (Of course, the colors are approximated into that 256 color pallette: hence the "Approx".) These colors are not affected (or should not be) by changes in the 16 color ANSI palette.

So for instance you can improve how, say, colorized `ls` appears without changing how your Vim syntax highlighting appears.

Another package that is useful is `ColorSamplerPack` which contains a whole bunch of color themes that you can experiment with one you have `CSApprox` installed.

These packages are found on http://www.vim.org.

Comment: I tried that with no luck.

The problem is I want to use vim-css-color plugin in terminal gim. And I am using zenburn colors for my terminal -in which blue and green colors have nothing to do with blue and green!.  So for example #0f0 looks like grey.

Comment: Works for me. I just went to `:colorscheme zenburn`, in a Vim running under PuTTY, and another one under Gnome Terminal to look at some C source. Both look exactly like the `gvim` zenburn screenshot at http://www.vi-improved.org/color_sampler_pack/ .  (Of course, they can't be exactly the same since the colors are approximated, but I can't tell the difference.) Sorry, don't know ahything about `vim-css-color-plugin`, like whether that plays along nicely with `CSApprox`. You cannot show arbitrary RGB colors in a terminal, only their nearby approximations from the 256 color xterm palette.

Comment: Either you didn't understand my question, or I didn't understand you.

Let me rephrase the problem: I redefine the blue color of terminal to something that is barely blue. So whenever I echo the ansi code of blue, I see this new color, not blue. This is because I find this new color look better than blue.

But when I am writing a css file, I want #00f to appear blue -real blue! Which is normally done by vim-css-color-plugin.  But since I changed the 'definition of blue' for the terminal, I don't get what I want.

So I was looking for a way, which resets the color definitions for vim sessions.

Comment: @sencer I understand you're changing the ANSI palette. What I don't understand is why that matters to the CSS plugin. Are you saying that this plugin works properly on terminals? Yet, if you change the ANSI blue, it screws up the rendering of `#00F`? How can the CSS plugin show a large number of different RGB colors, yet have a dependency on the ANSI palette? I'm going to install it and see what it's doing, and how/whether it interacts with `CSApprox`.

Comment: Terminal has 256 color support -as well as the vim-css-color plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution tough:

I removed the stuff changing my terminals definitions for colors and changed dircolors accordingly.