# Make Vim use the terminal colors again

Tags: vim, terminal, debian, xfce

I use Xfce4, and it seems that its terminal has been upgraded and now either supports 256 colors or is true-color (I'm not sure). These seem to be the relevant variables it exports:

```
COLORTERM=truecolor
TERM=xterm-256color
```

One of the unexpected changes it has caused is that now Vim no longer respects my palette. Instead, it is using its own set of colors. Moreover, it automatically sets `bg=dark` for some reason.

The closest I get to the colors I'm used to is setting `colorscheme peachpuff`. But what I would really like is to have Vim honouring the 16 colors that I chose to compose my palette over years of terminal usage.

I have searched for an answer, but the "closest" I found to an answer was actually the [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156492/change-terminal-colors-without-changing-vim-colors) of what I'm looking for.    :)

Comment: XFCE's default terminal emulator has supported 256color for many years. What's new is support for 24bit colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine TERM just when you invoke vim, with the terminal you want it to run with with:

```
TERM=vt100 vim  # instead of simply: vim
```

(even create an alias or a function for this)

```
VAR=value a_command  #invokes a_command, + temporarily sets in its environment: VAR=value
                     #This assignement is not done on the rest of your shell.
```

Other popular TERM values: xterm , or xterm-color